# Azure Text To Speech (TTS) fails with HTTP 400 Error on Japanese Characters

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, python-unicode

I’m a student using Python to access the REST API for the TTS Azure Cognitive Service.  I’m testing a file created with Azure’s online [Audio Content Creation Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-audio-content-creation) with the following (a Japanese translation of *I’m excited to try text to speech*):

```
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice xml:lang="ja-JP" xml:gender="Female" name="ja-JP-NanamiNeural">テキスト読み上げを試すのが楽しみです</voice></speak>
```

The file works when run in the tool, but fails with a HTTP 400 Error when I use the REST API.  However, when I use the following text as substitute for the Japanese Kanji, it also works on the REST API:  *Kisuto yomiage o tamesu no ga tanoshimidesu*

Here is a snippet of the code I use:

```
def send_text2(token,endpoint,uuid,ssml):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '  + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
        'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'audio-48khz-96kbitrate-mono-mp3',
        'User-Agent': 'Application for Final',
        'X-ClientTraceId': uuid

    }
    vocalize_request = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=ssml)
    print(vocalize_request.status_code)
    # Retrieve mp3 data and write to file
    with open(f"vocalized_file-{uuid}.mp3", "wb") as binary_file:
    #Write bytes to file
        binary_file.write(vocalize_request.content)
```

I have tried this code successfully on then original English, as well as German and Italian translations, so I'm confident of the endpoints used and the token being sent. I should note that Russian translations also fail with a HTTP 400 Error.

I have tried setting all xml:lang= “ja-JP”, ensuring the format is uff-8, and removing both the mstts and emo namespaces, all of which did not work.   I googled and found two other possible solutions, both of which also did not work: the first, explicitly NOT setting the Content-Length header, and the second, wrapping the translated text in a <! [CDATA[]]> (the second really shouldn’t have had any effect).

Any ideas what may be going on here?  I don’t think it’s a bug in TTS because the only account of something similar occurring seems to have been resolved (although, as I mentioned, not setting the Content-Length does not seem to work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue include multi-byte charactor in xml. You can escape string using xml.etree.ElementTree.

1. ssml for Japanese save to xml file. (UTF-8 with BOM format)
2. load ssml from xmlfile as follows:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
ssml = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf8')
```

3. execute post request with ssml

```py
send_text2(token,endpoint,uuid,ssml)
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  I am using at the Translation Service to translate a string in one language, and then immediately using the translation to create a mp3 using TTS in the translated language- I won't be saving anything to file but the mp3.  With that in mind, the safest best to avoid any issue is to parse any SSML strings I create with into a root Element using ET.fromstring(), and then dump that with ET.tostring().  I had no idea using multibyte characters in xml would be so fickle.... thanks again!